# NSMutableArray - Get Arrays Index Integer By Searching With A String

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray

I have been working with NSMutableArray and have had no problems retrieving an object from an array by using `objectAtIndex:int`.  Rather then pulling an object out of the array by an integer is their a way to get the index position by searching the array with a string.

```
animalOptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
//Add items
[animalOptions addObject:@"Fish"];
[animalOptions addObject:@"Bear"];
[animalOptions addObject:@"Bird"];
[animalOptions addObject:@"Cow"];
[animalOptions addObject:@"Sheep"];

NSString * buttonTitle = [animalOptions objectAtIndex:1];
// RETURNS BEAR

int * objectIndex = [animalOptions object:@"Bear"];
// THIS IS WHAT I NEED HELP WITH, PULLING AN INDEX INTEGER WITH A STRING (ex: Bear)
```

Hopefully this makes sense, and there is an answer out there, I have been unable to research online and find anything through google or apple's class references.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the `indexOfObject:` method from `NSArray`:

```
NSUInteger index = [animalOptions indexOfObject:@"Bear"];
```

If there are duplicate entries then the lowest index of that object is returned. For more information, take a look at the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:).

Comment: Will this work with two different NSStrings -- the one in the array and the parameter being passed? Or is the comparison "deep"?

Comment: Thank You! Amazingly quick response, This solved my question.

Comment: Yes – equality is tested by sending an `isEqual:` message to the object. An `NSString` instance will return YES if the string values are equal, even if they are two different instances.

Comment: You should use `NSUInteger`, not `int`, particularly if you intend to support 64-bit Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array indexOfObject:object] which will return the index of that  object, now with the way you are wanting to do it, it might not w ork since the string you are specifing is not the actual string object in the array doing this however will def work

```
NSString * buttonTitle = [animalOptions objectAtIndex:1];// RETURNS BEARint 
objectIndex = [animalOptions indexOfObject:buttonTitle] //this will return 1
```