# Keeping an array sorted - at setting, getting or later?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, oop, nsmutablearray, sorting

As an aid to learning objective c/oop, I'm designing an iOS app to store and display periodic bodyweight measurements. I've got a singleton which returns a mutablearray of the shared store of measurement object. Each measurement will have at least a date and a body weight, and I want to be able to add historic measurements.

I'd like to display the measurements in date order. What's the best way to do this? As far as I can see the options are as follows: 1) when adding a measurement - I override addobject to sort the shared store every time after a measurement is added, 2) when retrieving the mutablearray I sort it, or 3) I retrieve the mutablearray in whatever order it happens to be in the shared store, then sort it when displaying the table/chart.

It's likely that the data will be retrieved more frequently than a new datum is added, so option 1 will reduce redundant sorting of the shared store - so this is the best way, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a modified version of (1). Instead of sorting the complete array each time a new object is inserted, you use the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8180369/1187415 to insert the new object into the array at the correct place.

Then for each insert you have only a binary search to find the correct index for the new object, and the array is always in correct order.

Since you said that the data is more frequently retrieved than new data is added, this seems to be more efficient.

Comment: Right -- but don't override `addObject:` in an `NSMutableArray` subclass to do it.  Implement the insert-in-order logic at the location where the data is inserted in the model layer.

Answer (score 1):

If I forget your special case, this question is not so easy to answer. There are two basic solutions:

1. Keep array unsorted and when you try to access the element and array is not sorted, then sort it. Let's call it "lazy sorting".
2. Keep array sorted when inserting elements. Note this is not about appending new element at the end and then sort the whole array. This is about finding where the element should be (binary search) and place it there. Let's call it "sorted insert".

Both techniques are correct and useful and deciding which one is better depends on your use cases.

Example:

1. You want to insert hundreds of elements into the array, then access the elements, then again insert hundreds of elements, then access. In summary, you will be inserting values in big chunks. In this case, lazy sorting will be better.
2. You will often insert individual elements and you will access the elements often. Then sorted insert will have better performance.
3. Something in the middle (between inserting 1 and inserting tens of elements). You probably don't care which one of the methods will be used.

(Note that you can use also specialized structures to keep an array sorted, not based on `NSArray`, e.g. structures based on a balanced tree, while keeping number of elements in the subtree).